# Check javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror is a primitive type

Tags: java, types, primitive

Is there any way I can check that a `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror` is a primitive type? I've tried `instanceof PrimitiveType` but this always yields true since `PrimitiveType` extends TypeMirror.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: did you try looking at `TypeMirror.getKind()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html

> To implement operations based on the class of an TypeMirror object,
>   either use a visitor or use the result of the getKind() method. Using
>   instanceof is not necessarily a reliable idiom for determining the
>   effective class of an object in this modeling hierarchy since an
>   implementation may choose to have a single object implement multiple
>   TypeMirror subinterfaces.

Try calling `getKind()` rather than `instanceOf`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that part!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a [`TypeMirror`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html) object, you can get the kind of this type ([`TypeKind`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeKind.html)) with the [`getKind()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeMirror.html#getKind--) method and then use the [`isPrimitive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/TypeKind.html#isPrimitive--) method.

```
if(typeMirror.getKind().isPrimitive()){
     //It's a primitive type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

To check if it a primitive kind

```
typeMirror.getKind().isPrimitive()
```

or use a visitor to perform action if it is an instance of PrimitiveType

```
typeMirror.accept(new SimpleTypeVisitor6<P, R>() {
    @Override R visitPrimitive(PrimitiveType t, P p) {
      //do something with primitive type t
    }
}, null);
```